# Integrating MS Project with Bug Tracker .NET

Tags: .net, visual-studio, bug-tracking, ms-project, bugtracker.net

I am using MS Project and Bug traker .NET http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html for resource and project management.
There are few number of projects which are on MS Project and on Bug Tracker. Here I need a plug-in/add-in wherein I could integrate between the two to check for resource utilization and track which resource has been allocated where.
Any suggestions!

Comment: What do you mean "integrate"? MS Project creates files. It's Project Server that is a separate application with which you can integrate. With files, all you can do is load them into another application or update them periodically with changes from the other application.

Comment: Like I have a user 'A' assigned to project 'B', for which the record has been maintained on MS Project. And the same user 'A' has been assigned to another project 'C' on Bug Tracker. Now I want to check where and what all have been assigned to user 'A'. I want to fetch the records from both MS Project and Bug Tracker for that user. I hope this helps to understand the situation better.

Comment: You haven't realized what you are asking. Unless you use Project *Server* which provides a WS API, you can't check who is assigned to what. You'd have to open the file to do that, facing issues like locked files, conflicting changes etc. Doing this correctly is non-trivial

Comment: The underlying point here is, if we are using Project Server to track resources, then how can we fetch the data from Bug Tracker also and merge both the Project server data with it.